# Proof $f(x,y)=x_1+e^{x_{2}}$ is strictly convex

Tags: convex-analysis, definition, alternative-proof

I am trying to show that $f(x,y)=x_1+e^{x_2}$ is strictly convex.

I can show this using the Hessian Matrix which is positive definite.
However for some reason i can not put it together using algebra when it comes to two variables.

To be strictly convex then:
$f(t(x_1)+(1-t)(x_2)) < t(f(x_1))+(1-t)f(x_2))$

How do i proceed?

Comment: Since you've shown that your function is twice diff'ble with positive hessian at each point, you're done (it's a well-known theorem, based on Jensen's inequality). For a soft reference, look at section 3 (especially 3.2) of https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15381/slides/cvxopt.pdf

Comment: Except that $f$ is **not** strictly convex, only convex, for example $2f(3,5)<f(6,5)+f(0,5)$ fails since $2f(3,5)=f(6,5)+f(0,5)$.

Comment: "using the Hessian Matrix which is positive definite" Is it?

Answer (score 1):

This function is convex (it is the sum of two convex functions) but it is **not** strictly convex.

To see why, look at its behaviour on the line connecting $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, y)$ and $\mathbf{x}^\prime = (x_2, y)$. (Note that $y$ is fixed.) Then
$$f(t\mathbf{x}+(1-t)\mathbf{x}^\prime) = tx_1+(1-t)x_2+e^y = tf(\mathbf{x})+(1-t)f(\mathbf{x}^\prime)$$
You get an equality that is compatible with convexity, but not the strict inequality required for strict convexity.